# Does linking a Google account managed by an administrator to a personal account cause any security issues

Tags: gmail, google-account, privacy, google-workspace-for-business

I have a company-managed google account and I'm reading from here that the administrator has full access to all data on the account.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181692?hl=en&ref_topic=28745

> It’s important to note that your administrator or service provider has access to any data you store in this account, including your email.

Presumably, this means my employer can monitor whatever I say or do through the google account. But what happens if I link my account to my personal gmail account, would the linked accounts also be exposed to this privileged admin access?

Comment: I voted to move this to webapps, but it might do better in privacy.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question.  But in general, linking work and personal accounts is not a good idea, because of the potential consequences when you leave the company and thus lost access to the work account.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer accounts and Google Apps accounts, can't have the primary email address or alias of any those as an alternative email address. Also Gmail accounts doesn't allow to designate as delegate email access to an account out of the primary domain.

But if you set your Google Apps account to pull the messages from your personal Gmail account, the domain administrator could have access to your personal messages because they are in a mailbox under his control.

**References**
[Sign in to your Google Account with another email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176347)